# useReducer in Context consumer does not update the input state in the Login component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I added useReducer inside createContext file in order to use useContext to manage all user inputs and update the state after validating the inputs. But the input field does not response on any keystroke.

Here is my code:

reducer-context.js FILE

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

//this is my context

const ValContext = React.createContext({
  email: "",
  eValid: null,
  onChangeEmail: (e) => {},
  onEmailIsValid: () => {},
  password: "",
  pValid: null,
  onChangePassword: (e) => {},
  onPasswordIsValid: () => {},
});


//this is my initial states

export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: "",
  eValid: null,
  password: "",
  pValid: null,
};

//this is my reducer function

const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, actions) => {
  switch (actions.type) {
    case "EMAIL_INPUT":
      return {
        ...state,
        email: actions.payload,
        eValid: actions.payload.trim().includes("@"),
      };
    case "EMAIL_BLUR":
      return {
        ...state,
        email: state.email,
        eValid: state.email.trim().includes("@"),
      };
    case "PASSWORD_INPUT":
      return {
        ...state,
        password: actions.payload,
        pValid: actions.payload.trim().length >= 6,
      };
    case "PASSWORD_BLUR":
      return {
        ...state,
        password: state.password,
        pValid: state.password.trim().length >= 6,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

//my Context provider component

export const Validation = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    email: "",
    eValid: null,
    password: "",
    pValid: null,
  });
  console.log(state);
  const emailChangeHandler = (email) => {
    dispatch({ type: "EMAIL_INPUT", payload: email });
  };
  const passwordChangeHandler = (e) => {
    dispatch({ type: "PASSWORD_INPUT", payload: e.target.value });
  };
  const emailValidation = (e) => {
    dispatch({ type: "EMAIL_BLUR" });
  };
  const passwordValidation = (e) => {
    dispatch({ type: "PASSWORD_BLUR" });
  };
  return (
    <ValContext.Provider
      value={{
        email: state.email,
        eValid: state.eValid,
        onChangeEmail: (e) => emailChangeHandler(e),
        onEmailIsValid: emailValidation,
        password: state.password,
        pValid: state.pValid,
        onChangePassword: passwordChangeHandler,
        onPasswordIsValid: passwordValidation,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ValContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ValContext;
```

I was expecting all the state to be updated inside my Login.js component.

My Login.js Component

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Card from "../UI/Card/Card";
import classes from "./Login.module.css";
import Button from "../UI/Button/Button";
import AuthContext from "../../store/auth-context";
import ValContext, { Validation } from "../../store/reducer-context";

const Login = (props) => {
  const [formIsValid, setFormIsValid] = useState(false);
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

// this is the reducer-context api call
  const valCtx = useContext(ValContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormIsValid(valCtx.eValid && valCtx.pValid);
    return () => {};
  }, [valCtx.eValid, valCtx.pValid]);

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    authCtx.onLogin(valCtx.email, valCtx.password);
  };

  return (
    <Validation>
      <Card className={classes.login}>
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <div
            className={`${classes.control} ${
              valCtx.eValid === false ? classes.invalid : ""
            }`}
          >
            <label htmlFor="email">E-Mail</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              value={valCtx.email}
              onChange={valCtx.onChangeEmail}
              onBlur={valCtx.onEmailIsValid}
            />
          </div>
          <div
            className={`${classes.control} ${
              valCtx.pValid === false ? classes.invalid : ""
            }`}
          >
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              value={valCtx.password}
              onChange={valCtx.onChangePassword}
              onBlur={valCtx.onPasswordIsValid}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.actions}>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              className={classes.btn}
              disabled={!formIsValid}
            >
              Login
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </Card>
    </Validation>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: You're using the `useContext` hook outside of the provider. You need to make sure to use in inside any child component of `Validation`. You can create a wrapper component.

Comment: I wrapped my 'Login' component inside 'Validation' but am still having the same issue